# How can I use sneakers (for rabbitMQ) to requeue a message for up to 5 failed attempts?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, sneakers

I see the old gem versions supported the ability to define these sort of things within the `Sneakers.configure` params back around 2015, but this is no longer the case. So im trying to find alternatives, but the sneakers wiki do not have any details, and neither can i figure out any ways for it to be done looking through the source code for sneakers.

I need my worker to be able to "know" how many failed attempts a message has been attempted in order to choose whether to requeue or to reject the message

config

```rb
Sneakers.configure(
  heartbeat: 60,
  amqp: "amqp://#{ENV['RABBITMQ_USER']}:#{ENV['RABBITMQ_PASS']}@#{ENV['RABBITMQ_HOST']}",
  daemonize: ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production',
  pid_path: './sneakers.pid',
  vhost: '/',
  exchange: 'sneakers',
  exchange_type: :direct,
  timeout_job_after: 2.minutes,
  workers: 1,
  properties: {
    connection_name: 'worker'
  }
)
Sneakers.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

workers = Sneakers::Runner.new([Workers::BB])
workers.run
```

worker

```rb
module Workers
  ##
  class BB
    include Sneakers::Worker
    from_queue :backbone

    def work(msg)
      failed_atempts = 0 ## ! need to find out the failed attempt count

      ## ... handle message ...

      ack!
    rescue StandardError => e
      log :fatal, e.message
      log :fatal, e.backtrace
      
      requeue! if failed_attempts <= 5
      reject! if failed_attempts > 5
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

currently this is the only way i've figured out how to do it, I used `work_with_params` instead of `work`, and then I manually requeue the message using `publish` with manually configured custom headers

```rb
class Workman
  include Sneakers::Worker

  from_queue :my_queue

  def work_with_params(msg, _delivery_info, metadata)
    max_retry = 5
    headers = metadata[:headers]
    retry_count = headers['retry_count'] || 0

    ## ...

    ack!
  rescue StandardError => e
    retry_count += 1
    headers['retry_count'] = retry_count

    if retry_count > max_retry
      ## ... do something to stash failed messages for later processing
      stash_failed_message(@queue.name, msg, metadata, e)
    end

    if retry_count <= max_retry
      publish msg, routing_key: @queue.name, persistent: true, headers: { retry_count: retry_count }
    end

    ack!
  end
end
```